# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (102:56) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Everything was running fine on my local host until i decided to redownload "reduxjs/toolkit" again for some reason and then everything went wrong...I have no idea what to do the with this error. never had it until downloading the package again...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/610Ss.png)

I tried to delete redux toolkit nothing worked.
here is the actors.jsx code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8S50.jpg)

Comment: Show code of Actors.js  file

Comment: okay the code is there, i updated it thanks